# Validation is not working in 3 layered

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

My DAT/DAL class codes are fine.
In my business logic layer.. I want to validate the ID number using Regex validation.

```
private int idno;
    public int IDNO
    {
        get { return idno; }
        set
        {

            Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
            if(r.IsMatch(idno.ToString()))
                throw new Exception("Invalid length");
            idno = value;


        }

     public void AddStudent()
    {
        DAT.AddStudent(this.idno);
    }
     public DataTable ViewStudent()
    {
        return DAT.ViewStudent();
    }
```

Then in my presentation layer I called the Business logic layer in my Add button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BIZ b = new BIZ();
            b.IDNO = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text.ToString());


            b.AddStudent();

            GridView1.DataSource = b.ViewStudent();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

The validation is always "Input string was not in a correct format." I want that the validation would be what I've written in my BLL.. I mean in my BLL it validates already if the user typed in a string but why is it not throwing the BLL exception?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be performing any validation on the property's setter. Should it have read?

```
            Regex r = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
            if(r.IsMatch(value.ToString()))
                throw new Exception("Invalid length");
            this.idno = value;
```

Comment: What do you mean i'm not performing any validation? I want to validate if the user inputs letters not numbers.. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Its a bit unclear to me from the code you posted, but it looks like you are performing validation on idno which has not yet been assigned a value. I believe you intended to perform the validation on the 'value' being set. i.e. change if(r.IsMatch(idno.ToString())) to if(r.IsMatch(value.ToString()))

Comment: Ohh yeah I forgot to switch that.. But I changed and tried it now already but same exception is showing.